# Invalid conversion from runtime type Map<String,SObject> to Map<String,OrgWideEmailAddress>

Tags: apex, map, sobject

I am trying to cast the type `Map<String, SObject>` to `Map<String, EmailTemplate>`, my code as follows:

```
EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate LIMIT 1].get(0);

SObject sobj = (SObject) emailTemplate;

Map<String, SObject> sobjectMap = new Map<String, SObject>();

sobjectMap.put('red', sobj);

Map<String, EmailTemplate> emailTemplateByColorMap = (Map<String, EmailTemplate>) sobjectMap;
```

I am getting the following error message:

> Error on line 9, column 1: System.TypeException: Invalid conversion
>   from runtime type Map to Map
>   AnonymousBlock: line 9, column 1

Any idea why is throwing an error message? An SObject can be cast to EmailTemplate. Right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An SObject by itself can be cast to EmailTemplate, however, Map cannot, that happens, because you may have not only EmailTemplate as values in Map, but also other SObjects.

Example:

```
Map<String, SObject> sobjectMap = new Map<String, SObject>();
sobjectMap.put('red', new Account(Name = '123'));
sobjectMap.put('green', new Contact(LastName = '123'));
```

So you cannot convert Map, but you can retrieve your email template by key-color and cast it itself:

```
EmailTemplate redTemplate = (EmailTemplate) sobjectMap.get('red');
```